# RealmでValue of type 'Realm' has no member 'removeNotifications'のエラーが出ます

Tags: swift, realm

Realmを使用してみようと思いまして、以下のように記述した際

```
if token != nil {
    realm.removeNotifications(token)
```

の箇所で

`Value of type 'Realm' has no member 'removeNotifications'`と言われます。

どのような事が考えられますでしょうか。

```
var token: NotificationToken!

@IBAction func startButtonDidTap(sender: AnyObject) {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    if isUpdating == true {
        // Stop
        isUpdating = false
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        startButton.setTitle("Start", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        // Remove a previously registered notification
        if token != nil {
            realm.removeNotifications(token)  //Value of type 'Realm' has no member 'removeNotifications'
        }
    }
    else {
        // Start
        isUpdating = true
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        startButton.setTitle("Stop", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        // Add a notification handler for changes
        token = realm.addNotificationBlock {
            [weak self] notification, realm in
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmには`removeNotifications()`というメソッドはありません。昔は`removeNotification()`というメソッド（複数形のsがない）がありましたが、それもバージョン0.99で削除されました。

Realmの通知を解除するには、`token.stop()`メソッドを使ってください。

```
if let token = token {
    token.stop()
}
```

上記のように書きます。

参考： https://realm.io/jp/news/realm-objc-swift-0.99.0/

Comment: すみません！
本当にありがとうございます。
削除されたのですね。昨年書かれたものを参考にしていたのですが気付きませんでした。ありがとうございます。